# Runtime crash on java application with jdk 17.0.1 on Apple silicon

Tags: java, macos, crash, desktop-application, apple-silicon

I'm developing a desktop app with some friends, on linux and windows based on amd/intel processor the app works just fine but on my MacBook Air m1 the app just crash randomly and I'm not able to debug the crash-log.
Does anyone may help me on this?

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               java [1425]
Path:                  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
Identifier:            java
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        idea [1168]
Responsible:           idea [1168]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-12-15 10:37:49.6860 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        E61AAB9C-46E5-25CD-1606-A973D0634921


Time Awake Since Boot: 590 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        24  Java: InvokeLaterDispatcher

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4366696448
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      104468000-10446c000    [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...Home/bin/java

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Bug JDK-8275723](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8275723)and per comments in the bug upgrade to OpenJFX 17.0.2-ea+2 for your dependency. Doing this fixed the same issue for me.